# Query For Join Two Table

Tags: php, laravel

I have query in laravel, but I just want to know how query in php because I'm not familiar with php.

Here my query in laravel:

```
$data = DB::table('users')
            ->join('order_schedules','users.id','=','order_schedules.driver_id')
            ->select('order_schedules.driver_id','users.name','order_schedules.date_time')
            ->orderBy('date_time','asc')
            ->get();
```

users table = id,name,email and password.

order_schedules = id,driver_id ,type and date_time.

I just want to display id,name and date_time. I hope anybody can help me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "in php"? Do you want plain PHP for a database query? Or an SQL query like "SELECT ..."?

Comment: Sorry...i mean sql qery

Comment: Most queries in laravel you can get the SQL for by doing a `toSQL` in the end (in your case instead of `get`) and then printing the result of that somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full SQL query from Laravel's query builder easily.

```
$sql = DB::table('users')        
          ->join('order_schedules','users.id','=','order_schedules.driver_id')
          ->select('order_schedules.driver_id','users.name','order_schedules.date_time')
          ->orderBy('date_time','asc')
          ->toSql();
```

`$sql` will give the full sql query.

Furthermore, queries with bindings won't return the full query until you bind the values with the query as,

```
$query_buider = DB::table('users')        
                  ->join('order_schedules','users.id','=','order_schedules.driver_id')
                  ->select('order_schedules.driver_id','users.name','order_schedules.date_time')
                  ->orderBy('date_time','asc')
                  ->where('order_schedules.driver_id', 1) // Note this condition.
                ;

$sql = array_reduce($query_buider->getBindings(), function($sql, $binding){
    return preg_replace('/\?/', is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'".$binding."'" , $sql, 1);
}, $query_buider->toSql());
```

`$sql` will give the full sql query.

Furthermore, Anyone want to follow a DRY method to get the full SQL,

1. Add below macro function in **`AppServiceProvider`** **`boot()`** method.

   ```
   \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::macro('toFullSql', function(){
       return array_reduce($this->getBindings(), function($sql, $binding){
           return preg_replace('/\?/', is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'".$binding."'" , $sql, 1);
       }, $this->toSql());
   });
   ```
2. Add an alias to the Eloquent Builder.

   ```
   \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::macro('toFullSql', function(){
       return ($this->getQuery()->toFullSql());
   });
   ```
3. Then debug as usual.

   ```
   \Log::debug(User::first()->jobs()->toFullSql());
   ```